# Best practices for FCM registration token management clarification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm reading through FCM token management best practices in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) and have the following questions.

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration
> token for the client app instance... your app should retrieve this
> token at initial startup and save it to your app server alongside a
> timestamp.

Is the recommendation here to handle the token on app launch or just the first time the app is launched on install? Because I can't imagine given how many server interactions there are in the typical life of a client process that we wouldn't just update the token every time the app is launched and call it a day instead of creating additional tasks to keep these tokens fresh.

> We recommend that you periodically retrieve and update all registration tokens on your server.

Is the recommendation here to `null` stale tokens?

> We recommend that you periodically retrieve and update all registration tokens on your server. This requires you to add server logic to update the token’s timestamp at regular intervals, regardless of whether or not the token has changed.

I don't understand what this means. Is the recommendation here to task the server with updating a token's timestamp? What does this accomplish? And is the server capable of generating a token for a client?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, as I understand, you have to :

On client side :

- Store the token on your server on first launch (your server will consider that your token is valid for 2 months)
- Update your token on server if it changes

On server side:

- When a new token is registered store the token in your database and set his validity for 2 months (if the token already exist in your database then just reset his validity for 2 months again)
- When a notification send fails, then remove the invalid token from tour database
- Periodically (monthly suggested), validate all tokens and reset their validity date if valid (delete if not).

Comment: you can store your token and its last refresh date in a storage to see when it changes or needs to be refreshed - how do you find out its last refresh date?

Comment: @verunar When you persist the token on the client just store the current date. So on future lauch compare the stored date with the new current one.

Comment: Im also having problems understanding what to do with this token.

Yes, I store it in the Firestore database, but actually Im just using it when sending push notifications from Cloud Functions.

But what about when only sending push notifications to topics, how should I handle when the token is refreshed? Should I subscribe to topics again or?

Comment: @kragekjaer If the token is refreshed you have to subscribe the new one on the topic again. So if you are using a button to subscribe to a topic on the client, the user have to perform the button again (and this is not so good). One solution is to store all subscribed topics on the device storage in order to subscribe automatically again when the token is refreshed. This solution still not so good because the data can be deleted too. Another solution is to store all user subscribed topics on your database and subscribe the user to his topics (if needed) on logging.

Comment: Hi @Kaw, why should token older than X (2 in your sample) month are stale/expired? Perhaps the user has not open your app more than x month and no refreshing happens. So if you delete the token, the device receive no notifications any more.

Comment: Hi @Saftpresse99, you're right ! The doc has probably changed, I missed this mention: "Add server logic to update the token’s timestamp at regular intervals, regardless of whether or not the token has changed.". I edited my post, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The token is generated only when you first launch the app after install, and in some reset events. So your token will stay mostly the same, it won't change in every app launch. The timestamp is what the server will check. Maybe this will help:

### First Launch

1. Token generated, send to the server with timestamp

### Regular Launch

2. Token retrieved(same token), send again to the server periodically (2 Months?)

Now, this is where it gets hazy. As far as I understand, the server should signal the app in some way to get the token again (even if it is unchanged) to refresh the token in the server database and then refresh the timestamp.